# Use deserialize or getters and setters in controller actions

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

When implementing a rest json api with Symfony, one can deserialize the data for a create route with Jms Serializer:

```
$user = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Entity\User', 'json');
```

but this makes all parameters of the User Entity available to set from the POST request, which might not be that good.

An alternative to this is to use setters in the controller:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername($request->request->get('username'));
$user->sePassword($request->request->get('password'));
...
```

The latter option makes it more clear which parameters are actually able to set, but it requires a lot of code for a large entity.

What is the preferred way here?
Is it a third option?

Comment: So you are looking for a way to protect certain properties of your entity from being set by an API client?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: The general approach would be to use [forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html). A "form" is part of a system to handle updates rather than something that specifically needs to create a form on the frontend, it can be (and is) used for handling API requests (especially as it handles validation too). There is also a `@ReadOnly` annotation with JMSSerializer that you could add to properties that you don't want to be able to set by the deserialize process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize json data from your controller natively in Symfony once you have the [Serializer component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) installed.

```
$user = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Entity\User', 'json');
```

When your object is created via this method, using the json from your request (decoded and then denormalized), the setters of your object are utilized to populate the properties of your object.
Could you post your User Entity?

Alternatively you can use [Form Classes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) to perform this task.

> Modification in relation to the comment on your question.

Annotation Groups in your entities works for serialization and deserialization.

```
class Item
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"first", "second"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=100)
     * @Groups({"first"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=200)
     * @Groups({"second"})
     */
    private $description;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
}
```

If you had both "name" and "description" in your POST data, you could insert either into your entity with the following:

```
$object = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Entity\User', 'json', ['groups' => ['first']]);
```

Or

```
$object = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Entity\User', 'json', ['groups' => ['second']]);
```

In the first case, only the name property would be populated and only the description property in the second case.